# Android Drawable, receiving image from a socket

Tags: android, sockets, tcp, drawable, inputstream

I'm receiving an image through a socket in an android aplication, I did debugging and when I'm going to save the image in Drawable d, the program waits for something happens.
I think it has to have relation with clientSocket.getInputStream(); or with the socket.
I have a multithreading server in C++ and when I stop the server, the android aplication continues and I can see the image I sent before. But, I think it's not a server problem, because the socket in the server send the data and shows the message printf("Bytes enviados %d\n", bytesEnviados); which is at the end of the server code.

Here you have the code:

```
public Drawable mandaMensajeVideo(String mensaje, String ip, int puerto ) throws IOException{


    Socket clientSocket = new Socket(ip, puerto);
    DataOutputStream outToServer = new DataOutputStream(clientSocket.getOutputStream());
    outToServer.writeBytes(mensaje);
    outToServer.flush();


    InputStream inputStream = clientSocket.getInputStream();


    Drawable d = Drawable.createFromStream(inputStream, null);


    clientSocket.close();

    outToServer.close();

    return d;
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Do you close the connection on the server side, or signal the end of the transmission in any other way?

Comment: I do free(ssock); in the server side

Comment: but I don't do ssock.Close();

Comment: But I send another kind of information like strings and I receive it in the client side

Comment: Sounds like the end of the `inputStream` is never reached, as you never properly close the communication.

Comment: Thank you! That was the answer!!

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like the end of the `inputStream` is never reached, as you never properly close the communication.